# How can I fix this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm scraping the flipkart website. What changes do I need to make in the code so that this error is gone and the element name will be printed?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
r=requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off")
c=r.content
a=soup(c,"html.parser")
all=a.find_all("div",{"class":"bhgxx2 col-12-12"})
b=len(all)

print(all[1].find_all("div",{"class":"_3wU53n"})[1].get_text)
```

*output*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(all[1].find_all("div",{"class":"_3wU53n"})[1].get_text)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Praneet and welcome to Stack Overflow!
I ran your code and it seems to me that you're seeing the `IndexError: list index out of range` error because `BeautifulSoup` actually can't find a a `div` with `class=_3wU53n` in the HTML and therefore returns an empty list (`[]`).
You can check for yourself by changing your last line to:
`print(all[1].find_all("div",{"class":"_3wU53n"})`
Since the list is empty you obviously can't access any element in it since there are none.

Answer (score 0):

`print(all[1].find_all("div",{"class":"_3wU53n"})[1].get_text)` will give only one value of index zero and you use index 1 that is why it gives an error.